# Git push HEAD commit detached to remote/master

Tags: git, github

When I do `git log -3 --oneline`, I get the following output:

```
c42e88d (HEAD) Error handling: Bug fix
f5d394d (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Show Details
7d465b6 enhancement
```

When I do `git branch`, I get the following:

```
* (HEAD detached from f5d394d)
master
```

How can I push the HEAD commit c42e88d to remote master?
I tried `git push origin master` but I am getting `Everything up-to-date`. What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to make your local `master` branch move forward to that commit :

```
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only c42e88d

# you can then :
git push origin master
```

If you want to stay in detached `HEAD` state and just push the current commit :

```
git push origin HEAD:master
# or
git push origin c42e88d:master
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
git push origin HEAD:master
```

`git push origin master` is short for `git push origin refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master`. The former `refs/heads/master`, as the source ref,  means the master in the local repository, and the latter, as the target ref, means the master in the remote repository. As `HEAD` and `master` do not point at the same commit, it's not right to use `git push origin master`.

If you really want to use `git push origin master`, you need to merge the detached HEAD to the local master first:

```
git checkout master
git merge c42e88d 
# in your case you can also use "git reset" in stead of "git merge"
# git reset c42e88d --hard
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

### What is a `detached HEAD`?

The `HEAD` points to the current branch/commit you have checked out. You can push if the `HEAD` points to a branch (the normal case).

If your head points to a commit, however, this is named `detached HEAD` as you have no branch checked out (the `HEAD`  is detached from any branch.

In other words, you have checked out the commit but pushed `master` which does not have the commit.

### How to fix it

In order to get rid of the detached `HEAD`, simply check out a branch:

```
git checkout master
```

Your `HEAD` then points to the `master` branch.

If your commit is not visible there but you want to push it, you have two possibilities:

- **Copy** the **one** commit to master using `git cherry-pick c42e88d`
- Set `master` to point to `c42e88d` using `git reset HEAD`. However, you might lose changes if they are committed in `master` but not in `c42e88d`.

In your case, all commits from master also exist in the history of `c42e88d` so both options do the same thing.

If you have uncommitted changes, you might want to `stash` them before running the `checkout` and pop the `stash` after resetting/cherry-picking.